# Meteor collection-revisions error

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-collections, meteor-packages

I'm using the [collection-revisions](https://atmospherejs.com/todda00/collection-revisions) package on Meteor to display all changes made in a collection.

However, I'm having some issues to restore previous changes. I'm getting an error: `Uncaught Error: Match error: Expected string, got undefined`.

I'm using the following event (similar to the documentation's example, actually):

```
Template.edit.events({
  'click .revert': function(e, t) {
    var edit;
    edit = Template.parentData();
    return CollectionRevisions.restore('Edits', edit._id, this.revisionId);
  }
});
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: this likely means that either `edit._id` or `this.revisionId` is undefined. log them and see which one is missing (and what `this` actually contains in your context).

Comment: yeah, i was forgetting to send `e` as a parameter at `Template.parentData(e);` - now i'm getting another error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'field' of undefined` but it seems to be an issue with the package itself (as the error is related to a package file), so i'll try to dig into it later.

Comment: for others having the same issue: there's an open question on [GitHub](https://github.com/todda00/meteor-collection-revisions/issues/3) about this since July, so maybe the package's author is no longer supporting it.